# How do I edit Data in a text file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a ticker, that has two buttons that raise and lower the value by one each time the corresponding button is clicked. I would also like this to be equal with the value of a number located in a text file. For example, the value of both the counter and the file are zero. I press the "+1" button, now both the counter and the number in the file are equal to 1. How might i do this? So far this is all i have been able to do because php is all executed at once.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Ticker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/ticker.css" />
    <script src="../resources/js/ticker.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="box">    
        <label for="qty"><abbr title="Quantity">Qty</abbr></label>
        <input id="qty" value="<?php echo file_get_contents('Data.txt'); ?>" />
        <button id="down" onclick="modify_qty(-1)">-1</button>
        <button id="up" onclick="modify_qty(1)">+1</button>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you'll need to commit the changes to the file in your php script. An asynchronous request would be best, but you can do it synchronously it will just be a totaled value rather than a consistently incremented one. In essence the value in the file is not getting modified because it is not actually ever getting changed.

Comment: it is a javascript function, this modifies the displayed number, but doesn't also modify the number stored in the text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On load:
PHP is executed; value is put in file.

On click:
JS vars are changed; file value is not modified because there is no request to modify the file, either from the js file or controlling php method.

Possible Solution:
When '+' or '-' is clicked send an asynchronous js request to php controller and have `file_put_contents` write new value to  'Data.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Use an ajax call and put the the file updation code in the ajax target php file. So that each time you click, you will not be reloading the page but sending ajax requests.